# M:N relation with more fields

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

So far the relations M:N I've built are simple intermediate tables where Doctrine does not need to create an entity for this table.

I have two entities Product and ingredient, they have a relationship M:N easily describe with Doctrine as follows. but the real problem is when i need store a `amount` field in the relation (I need to list the ingredients and also the amount).

**How can solve this?**

```
class Product {
     //...
     /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Ingredient", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_ingredient",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $ingredient;
     //...

class Ingredient {
    // ...
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="ingredient")
     */
    private $product;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it without intermediate entity really, that's why doctrine docs says that `ManyToMany` relationships are rare.
It's also the easiest thing to do, just add `RecipeItem` entity which will store information about `Ingredient` and amount and link it with relationship of `ManyToOne` to `Product`

#### Edit

Since I was asked to provide an example:

```
class Product {
     //...
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RecipeItem", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $ingredients;
     //...

class RecipeItem {
    // ...
    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="ingredients")
    **/
    private $product;

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ingridient")
    **/
   private $ingredient;

   /** 
    * @Column(type="decimal")
    **/ 
    private $amount;
}

class Ingredient {
    // Don't use bidirectional relationships unless you need to
    // it impacts performance
}
```

Now having a product you can simply:

```
foreach($product->getIngridients() as $item){
    echo "{$item->getAmount()} of {$item->getIngridient()->getName()}";
}
```

Comment: can provide a example

Comment: when I go to save I always get the following error `The identifier product is missing for a query of MyBundle\Entity\RecipeItem ...`

Comment: @rkmax: Sorry for the late answer, you've got to add following to your id key:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies